# KeyError - dictionary value/key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm loop through all items in a dictionary, use the syntax: `for key, value in questions.items()`, where `questions` is the dictionary name. This will assign `key` to be the dictionary key, and `value` to be the dictionary value.

Why I'm getting the error below?

```
line 13, in <module>
    ans = input("What is the capital of " + questions[value] + " ? ")
KeyError: 'y'
```

```
q1 = input("Please enter a country: ")
a1 = input("Please enter its capital: ")
q2 = input("Please enter a country: ")
a2 = input("Please enter its capital: ")

questions = {q1 : a1, q2 : a2}
score = 0
for key, value in questions.items():
    ans = input("What is the capital of " + questions[value] + " ? ")
    if ans == questions[key]:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!!")

print("Final score is: ", score)
```

Comment: it should be just `value`, not `questions[value]`. (It could be `questions[key]` but that seems perverse when this is guaranteed to be equal to `value`.)

Answer (score 2):

You could save yourself a lot of confusion by naming your variables meaningfully. For example, in your loop, you could use

```
for country, capital in questions.items():
```

You obviously wouldn't write `ans = input("What is the capital of " + questions[capital] + " ? ")` when you want to just use the capital. Dictionaries only map one way: you can only check for a country as a key, not a capital. `capital` is not a valid key, so to avoid the error:

```
    ans = input(f"What is the capital of {country}? ")
```

Using string summation is fine, but f-strings are nicer in my opinion, and sort of the de-facto convention since their introduction.

The whole point of iterating over `items` is exactly that you don't have to do repeated lookups:

```
    if ans == capital:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Its cause your are iterating over a dictionary with `dictionary.items()` which returns both the key and the value.

Then you are trying to retrieve the value from the dictionary by the value and not the key.

```
for key, value in questions.items():
    ans = input("What is the capital of " + value + " ? ") # <-- Just use the value
    if ans == questions[key]:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!!")
```

If you want to use the key to retrieve the value then use `questions[key]`.

However I think what you are trying to do is the question is the key of the dictionary while the answer is the value.

In that case do
`ans = input("What is the capital of " + key + " ? ")`

Comment: You’ve got the key and value the wrong way round. It should be: What is the capital of {key}?

Comment: That is at the end of my answer.

Comment: Ok, so does that mean your answer is not very clear?